# No debug symbols for watchOS 2.2.2

Tags: xcode7, watchos-2

After updating my Apple Watch to version 2.2.2, Xcode won't let me debug it: `no symbols for paired Apple Watch`. My Xcode version is 7.3.1 (7D1014). Looks like there's no .dmg file with the proper debug symbols. Anyone knows a fix/workaround? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also having this issue.